# How to map an array index to a certain date?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jcalendar

I want to map an index from my 3D array to a date. I have an array (sortedData[34][12][31]) and I would like to have it so that if a date is selected from JCalendar it corresponds to the correct index in my array. E.g. say the date 01/01/1974 is selected I would like it to map to sortedData[0][0][0].

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a java.util.Calendar object to get the day, month and year of the date:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(theDate);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Then get the indices in your array using

```
int i = year - 1974;
int j = month;
int k = day;
```